# Determine Joda DateTimeZone out of two strings

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

My problem:

1. I have a time as string in unix time. Unix time is always UTC.
2. I have a second time as string without any timezone info, but it should be equal to unixTime string, so it should be possible to determine the datetime zone with info from point 1.
3. I have an extra time string without any time zone info, but I know, that it has the same time zone as point 2.

How can I get the time zone for point 3?

Example:

```
//Point 1
String justTimeStringInUnixTime = "1280750400";

//Point 2
String justTimeStringAsDateString = "2010-08-02 14:00:00";

//Point 3
String extraString = "2015-03-24 09:33:03";

DateTimeZone timezone= getTimeZone(justTimeStringInUnixTime ,justTimeStringAsDateString);

//parse the extraString as DateTime
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(timezone);
DateTime dateTime= formatter.parseDateTime(extraString);

//some work with dateTime object ...
```

I have no idea at the moment. Perhaps someone can point me to the needed idea/code snippet.

Comment: How do you want to find the zone out of thin air? If the provider of the data has not told you how to interprete a date-time without tz info then you are lost. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A bit crude maybe, but this should work:

```
long ref = Integer.parseInt(justTimeStringInUnixTime) * 1000l;
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date j = form.parse(justTimeStringAsDateString);
long offset = j.getTime() - ref;
TimeZone tz = new SimpleTimeZone((int) offset, "UTC" + (offset == 0 ? "" : String.format("%+d", ((int) offset/3600000))));

DateTimeZone timezone= DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(tz);
```